# Implementing async return Types on .NET Standard

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-standard

Hello guys i am trying to create my own `Task`-Like types using the `AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute` for the .NetCore framework.
So far in .`Net Core` my custom `Type` works and it can be `awaited` and i can return it as `async [MyTypeName]<T> MyMethod()` instead of `Task` .
However in `.NetStandard 2.0` the attribute is not present and and i tried to implement it:
I decorated my awaitable type with the attribute but it still does not let me use it: `"The return type of an async method must be void,Task,Task<T>"`

So far i can use something like this in .`Net Core` and it works !!

```
public async Task WrapperMethod(){
   int result=await GetIntAsync();
}
public async Errand<int> GetIntAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  return 3;
}
```

**Attribute**:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Delegate, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute : Attribute {
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   builderType:
        public AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute(Type builderType) {
            this.BuilderType = builderType;
        }

        //
        public Type BuilderType { get; }
    }
```

Below are the implementation of the custom type and the `async method builder`.The `awaiter` is not important in this case but i can provide the source if needed.
 **My `Task`-Like Type**

```
[AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(Builder))]
    public partial class Errand {

        private readonly Builder mbuilder;
        public Errand() {
        }
        internal Errand(Builder methodBuilder) => this.mbuilder = methodBuilder;

        private readonly HashSet<Awaiter> awaiters = new HashSet<Awaiter>();

        protected bool isCompleted = false;

        public Awaiter GetAwaiter() {

            Awaiter result = new Awaiter(this);
            this.awaiters.Add(result);
            return result;
        }

    }
```

The custom `AsyncMethodBuilder` implementation:

```
public partial class Builder {

            #region " Compiler integration "

            public static Builder Create() {
                return new Builder();
            }

            protected IAsyncStateMachine myStateMachine;

            public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine {
                this.myStateMachine = stateMachine;
                this.errand = new Errand(this);
                stateMachine.MoveNext();
            }


            public void SetException(Exception ex) {

            }

            public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine machine) where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine {

                var foo = machine as IAsyncStateMachine;
                awaiter.OnCompleted(() => { foo.MoveNext(); });
            }
            public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine machine)where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine {

                IAsyncStateMachine asyncMachine = machine as IAsyncStateMachine;
                awaiter.OnCompleted(() => asyncMachine.MoveNext());

            }

            private Errand errand;
            public Errand Task { get { return this.errand; } }


            public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) {

            }
            public void SetResult() {

            }

            #endregion


            //  internal void AddAwaiter(Awaiter awaiter) => this.awaiters.Add(awaiter);

        }
```

What else should i add for it to work in .Net Standard?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes you can. It's like `ExtensionAttribute` - the compiler expects to find the attribute in the right namespace, but will use it from wherever it can find it. I wouldn't recommend it (preferring to use a nuget package), but it's doable. My guess is that the OP isn't using a C# 7 compiler, but it's quite hard to tell.

Comment: Note that the attribute must be declared in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace - we can't tell from the code posted whether that's where it's actually declared.

Comment: @DaisyShipton that's actually the correct answer - OP puts it in wrong namespace.

Comment: @Evk: Well it may be... but we can't tell for sure. I'm not sure I want to add an answer on a hunch.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I just verified it works fine on .NET standard, if you put attribute in right namespace (and produces error from post if you don't).

Comment: I am using the C# latest minor version.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian but can you put your attribute in right namespace and tell us if that resolved the problem or not?

Comment: My attribute is placed in an arbitrary folder.Where should i place it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the source file is for the attribute, but it does need to have the right namespace declaration:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Delegate, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute(Type builderType) =>
            BuilderType = builderType;
        public Type BuilderType { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooooh you are right :D Sorry i was thinking i have to somehow put it in the source of the SDK.